# Is there a way to read fields of an array of class objects in dafny

Tags: dafny

Say I had a Player class in dafny with a field called score I want to sort on. Is there a way in dafny where I could access the fields of the class outside the class. This is a snippet:

```
predicate PlayersSorted(a: array<Player>)
reads a
{
  forall j, k :: 0 <= j < k < a.Length ==> a[j].score <= a[k].score
}
```

This give the error `insufficient reads clause to read field` when trying to access the score field but I can't seem to find a read clause that would allow me to do this in the manual. If that's not possible can anyone offer a suggestion on a how you would go about verifying a sort on a class like object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `reads` clause for the array elements, such as `reads set x | x in a[..]`.

Going forward, you might also want to look into Chapter 9 (Dynamic Frames) of http://leino.science/papers/krml221.pdf for some idioms when working with the `modifies`/`reads` clauses.